# ObservableObject and Condition

Tags: timer, conditional-statements, swiftui

I have a code for a timer that starts automatically and should stop again with an if statement. Unfortunately, that doesn't work and I don't get an error message. what am I doing wrong here?

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

class WaitingTimerClass: ObservableObject {

    @Published var waitingTimerCount: Int = 0
    var waitingTimer = Timer()

    func start() {
        self.waitingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer  in self.waitingTimerCount += 1 } }

    func stop() { waitingTimer.invalidate() }

    func reset() { waitingTimerCount = 0; waitingTimer.invalidate() }

}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var observed = WaitingTimerClass()

    var body: some View {

        Text("\(self.observed.waitingTimerCount)")
            .onAppear {
                self.observed.start()
                    if self.observed.waitingTimerCount == 3 {
                        self.observed.stop()
                        }
                    }
        }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}



``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in `onAppear` block works only once, when the `View` appears (or several times, when view disappear and appear again). In your case `waitingTimerCount` will always be 0. If you need to observe some value from the view use `onReceive`. The code should looks like this:

```swift
struct TimerWaiter: View {

    @ObservedObject var observed = WaitingTimerClass()

    var body: some View {

        Text("\(self.observed.waitingTimerCount)")
            .onAppear {
                self.observed.start()
        }
        .onReceive(observed.$waitingTimerCount) { count in
            guard count == 3 else { return }
            self.observed.stop()
        }
    }

}
```

**update** for first author's comment: I can't figure out, why reseting timer is not working as expected and I have not much time today. Maybe tomorrow it will be easier to understand. Here is not quite good, but worked solution:

```swift
class WaitingTimerClass: ObservableObject {

    @Published var waitingTimerCount: Int = 0
    var didInvalidate = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var waitingTimer = Timer()

    func start() {
        self.waitingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer  in self.waitingTimerCount += 1 } }

    func stop() { waitingTimer.invalidate() }

    func reset() {
        waitingTimer.invalidate()
        waitingTimerCount = 0
        didInvalidate.send()

    }

}

struct TimerWaiter: View {

    @ObservedObject var observed = WaitingTimerClass()
    @State private var count = 0

    var body: some View {

        Text("\(count)")
            .onAppear {
                self.observed.start()
        }
        .onReceive(observed.$waitingTimerCount) { count in
            self.count = count
            guard count == 3 else { return }
            self.observed.reset()
        }
        .onReceive(observed.didInvalidate) { _ in
            self.count = 0
        }
    }

}
```

**P.S.** I will try to dig deeper to understand, why the last changing of `waitingTimerCount` does not affect View

Comment: Works. And I got it. Thank you. But why doesn't it work with reset ()? The counter stops but is not set to 0.

Comment: @cris now I can't figure out, why it ```reset()``` func does not work as expected. I'll try to understand it tomorrow, maybe. I added some hotfix, maybe it will be helpful

Comment: I'm curious. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
.onAppear {
    self.observed.start()
    if self.observed.waitingTimerCount == 3 {
        self.observed.stop()
    }
}
```

How this code works?

it is running when the View Appears (most likely only once)

1. start the timer
2. checked if waitinigTimer == 3 // it is not 3 at this moment
3. return

So, it simply never stop, as you already know.

If you like to stop it if waitingTimer == 3, you have to do it in your model.

```
@Published var waitingTimerCount: Int = 0 {
    willSet {
        if newValue == 3 { stop() }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. the solution to the reset problem can be found here:

[ObservableObject bug or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476678/observableobject-bug-or-not)